# Usage of Volatile.Write() instead of volatile in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, volatile

Assume the following code (note that this is only an example code):

```
public async void UnsafeMethod()
{
  int unsafeValue = 0;

  Task.Run(() => unsafeValue = 42 ); // set unsafeValue to some value
  await Task.Delay(10);              // wait for some time

  Assert.AreEqual(42, unsafeValue);  // check if unsafeValue has the new value
}
```

(Assume here that the CPU is idle and executes the task immediately.)

Since the task will be executed on a new thread, the new value of `unsaveValue` might not be visible to other threads due to possible caching issues. If i want to make the change visible, i would have to use `volatile` and make the local variable a field:

```
private volatile int safeValue = 0;

public async void SafeMethod()
{
  Task.Run(() => safeValue = 42 ); // set safeValue to some value
  await Task.Delay(10);            // wait for some time

  Assert.AreEqual(42, safeValue);  // check if safeValue has the new value
}
```

(Assume again that the task is executed immediately.)

My question now is, if the following will do the same while keeping the local variable (i know, the compiler makes it a field anyways...):

```
public async void AnotherMethod()
{
  int safeValue = 0;

  Task.Run(() => Volatile.Write(ref safeValue, 42); // set safeValue to some value
  await Task.Delay(10);                             // wait for some time

  Assert.AreEqual(42, safeValue);                   // check if safeValue has the new value
}
```

(Task gets executed immediately.)

The documentation is not entirely clear to me. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.volatile(v=vs.110).aspx

It states:

> On a multiprocessor system, a volatile write operation ensures that a
>   value written to a memory location is immediately visible to all
>   processors.

which is what I want. However, it also states:

> Writes the specified value to the specified field. On systems that
>   require it, inserts a memory barrier that prevents the processor from
>   reordering memory operations as follows: If a read or write appears
>   before this method in the code, the processor cannot move it after
>   this method.

at the method description, which I am not sure if this is what I want.

Again my question: Will the last code snipped do what i want it to do (make the write immediately visible to other threads)?

Comment: You definitely want to use `Volatile.Write()` instead of `volatile`. In fact, [Eric Lippert says you should avoid `volatile`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/06/16/atomicity-volatility-and-immutability-are-different-part-three/).

Comment: IMHO, `Assert.AreEqual(42, safeValue);` doesn't know about the call to `Volatile.Write`, so `safeValue` may be cached. I guess that `Volatile.Read`(when you call `Assert.AreEqual`) would be preferred...

Comment: Matteo is correct - you need to use `Volatile.Write()` for every write and `Volatile.Read()` for ever read (of the thread-shared field).

Comment: thanks guys, I have used the Volatile.Write and Volatile.Read as you said. I can't say for sure that it's working tho (it is working up to now).

Comment: Why do you think that compiler makes a local variable a field?

Comment: @VMAtm : I sadly don't have the source at hand but at some point i read that using a local variable inside a new task, thread or whatever will make the variable a field because the local variable could already be "gone" when the task is executed. (This has something to do with closures.) For me this made sense so i stuck to it and didn't dig any deeper. Note that I am not an expert on this and this information might be totally wrong.

Comment: No, you're absolutely correct about the closures and their internal structures, I just thought that you're talking about all the local variables.

Answer (score 0):

As **Matteo Umili** and  **Matthew Watson** mentioned in the comments you have to use `Volatile.Read` when you read a non-volatile field. That's because synchronization is always a 2 player game.

In this case `Volatile.Write` inserts store-release barrier after the write and `Volatile.Read` sets load-acquire barrier before the read.

Comment: I am still not sure if the "synchronization" on the hardware part is included (i.e. if the caches are written back to memory immediately). From the software point of view it works. However, I am not sure how to guarantee or test that the physical memeory assignment is actually not cached.

Comment: What happens in the hardware  depends on the JIT and the particular CPU. Even if you use `Interlocked.MemoryBarrier` which currently translates to a LOCKed operation which flashes the write buffers, it doesn't guaranty that the other CPUs will see the writes "immediately" and take them into account because there are read buffers in front of them. So don't think of it on the hardware level. Volatile is about atomicity and memory barriers. Think how memory accesses relate to each other and how barriers prevent reordering of them.